# How to attached source file in Eclipse?

Tags: java

I am getting below error when i am trying to run test method

The Jar file C:/Users/akrishna/eclipse/jre/lib/rt.jar has no source attachment.
You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below.

What is source that needs to be attached. And how to attach it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have JDK installed in your computer, it is automatically detected by eclipse but if not follow the below step.

Add JDK through `"Windows/Preferences": Java > Installed JREs`

You need to link to the root directory of the jdk installed. `rt.jar` is included in jdk installed directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in JDK installation, eg

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\src.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows OS only Solution.

1. Click on "attach source" Link
2. In the window that opens, select "External location"
3. In "Path" option click on "External File..." Button which should open Windows selection box that only accepts "*.jar" and ".zip" files.
4. Navigate to a location where you have installed your java which is usually at a location  for eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74
5. Look For file name src.zip, select that folder and click ok. So The final location will be eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\src.zip

This should attach the source files and you should be able to see the classes.